# SuperBoxSelect in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs4

I have downloaded SuperBoxSelect which is supported in Extjs3, but I want to use it in Extjs 4.

I have define `class` and `extend` it as needed in Extjs 4, and remove `Ex.ns()` and `Ext.reg()`.

But when I run the code I got bellowed error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'superclass' of undefined
```

So what I need to do to use it in Extjs 4?

Code:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.form', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect',
    alias: 'widget.superboxselect',
    .....
    .....
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this [Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134751-Ext.ux.form.field.BoxSelect-Intuitive-Multi-Select-ComboBox).

ExtJS3's plugin can't use in ExtJS4.

[image]

Comment: I have used that but it is not working correctly. sometimes all previous selection are removed.

Comment: @Kunal - The linked addon has had several updates since you asked your question, and I believe the problems you experienced are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

there is a 5.x framework component [Ext.form.field.Tag](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/src/Tag.js.html#Ext.form.field.Tag), which does just that:

```
Ext.form.field.Tag
```

or aliased:

```
xtype: 'tagfield'
```

Comment: seems not to be available in version 4

Comment: @joe Ext.form.field.ComboBox can be extended (eg. by dropping the absent file into the SDK directory or by creating a custom class), so that the class and xtype will be known.